# Sorting an Integer Array According to their No. of Factors (Zoho Placement Questions)

Tags: java, arrays, zoho

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecreasingIntAccToFactors {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Static Way of Array Creation
        // int[] a = { 3, 4, 7, 8, 16, 33 };

        // Dynamic Way of Array Creation
        System.out.print("Enter the Size of an Array :- ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the Elements of an Array [ " + i + " ] :- ");
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int[] f_count = new int[a.length];

        // Creating a Count Array to Store the No. of Factors that a Number has
        // According to their Array order
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = a[i] - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                if (a[i] % j == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            f_count[i] = count;
        }

        // Printing the Given Array with the Help of Method
        System.out.println("Given Array : - ");
        printingArray(a);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Factors of the Given Array :-");
        printingArray(f_count);

        // Sorting the Count Array and Swapping the Given Array
        for (int i = 0; i < f_count.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < f_count.length - 1; j++) {
                if (f_count[j] < f_count[j + 1]) {
                    // Swapping elements of the Count Array
                    int temp_c = f_count[j];
                    f_count[j] = f_count[j + 1];
                    f_count[j + 1] = temp_c;
                    // Swapping the Elements according to Count Array
                    int temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }

            }
        }

        // Printing the Resultant Array with the help of Method
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("Resultant Array : - ");
        printingArray(a);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The Factors of the Resultant Array :-");
        printingArray(f_count);

    }

    // Printing the Array
    public static void printingArray(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

I approached this problem with creating a new Array for the factors that the numbers had, and and sorted the factors, during the sorting of factors i swapped the elements of the given array

Is there any logical ways to solve them in a easy way?

The question is:

> Arrange the given numbers in the decreasing order of their number of
> factors.
>
> Input: 4,2,8,16,5
>
> Output: 16,8,4,5,2 (or) 16,8,4,2,5

Comment: If this problem is from a website, please include a link to the page that has the problem. If you cannot post a working link, it would help to describe the problem the code is intended to solve. Even though we can follow the code, it is helpful to check if the code seems to match the description

Comment: So, what is your question? Does the code you have shown work, and you want to see if it can be improved? The question might be more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned about performance, if the array is very large?

You can improve your bubble sort slightly. After the first iteration of the outer `for` loop, the inner `for` loop would have moved the element with the greatest number of factors to the beginning of the array. So, on the next iteration, that element can be skipped over. So, you should be able to change `for (int j = 0; j < f_count.length - 1; j++) {` to `for (int j = i; j < f_count.length - 1; j++) {`. That will reduce the number of comparisons by about half.

However, either way, the number of comparisons will be O(n^2). There are faster sorts, such as merge sort, which run in O(n log n). Java offers built in sorts, in the [`Arrays` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) and the [`Collections` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html).

The sort methods in the `Arrays` API that are overloaded for primitives sort only using the "natural order". But, you don't want to sort by the "natural order" for integers. You want to create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html), which will allow you to provide logic to make the comparisons. To do that, you will want to have an array or `Collection` of Objects, not of primitives.

You could put your data into a `List<Integer>` or an array of `Integer`. That will allow use of the sort methods in `Collections` or `Arrays` that accept a `Comparator` argument. But, that would result in repeated calculations of each element. Potentially, there would be `2 * n * lg n` calculations of factors.

Since you have to have an Object to use the built in sorts, why not have a `class` in which each instance has the original value and the number of factors?

```
package decreasingintacctofactors; 

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecreasingIntAccToFactors {

    static class NumberFactorPair {

        int number;
        int factorCount;

        NumberFactorPair() {
        number = 0;
        factorCount = 0;
    }

    NumberFactorPair(int num) {
        number = num;
        factorCount = 2; // number is a factor of itself, 
                         // and 1 is a factor
        for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                factorCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}



static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Static Way of Array Creation
    // int[] a = { 3, 4, 7, 8, 16, 33 };
    //        NumberFactorPair [] a = {
    //              new NumberFactorPair ( 3), new NumberFactorPair ( 4)
    //            , new NumberFactorPair ( 7), new NumberFactorPair ( 8)
    //            , new NumberFactorPair (16), new NumberFactorPair (33)
    //        };

    // Dynamic Way of Array Creation
    System.out.print("Enter the Size of an Array :- ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    NumberFactorPair [] a = new NumberFactorPair [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print
           ("Enter the Elements of an Array [ " + i + " ] :- ");                     
        a[i] = new NumberFactorPair (sc.nextInt());            
    }    
    
    Arrays.sort (a, new Comparator<NumberFactorPair>() { 
        @Override
        public int compare (NumberFactorPair nf1, NumberFactorPair nf2) {
            return Integer.compare (nf2.factorCount, nf1.factorCount);
        }
    });    

    // Printing the Given Array with the Help of Method
    System.out.println("Given Array : - ");
    printingArray(a, false);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The Factors of the Given Array :-");
    printingArray (a, true); 

    // Printing the Resultant Array with the help of Method
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("Resultant Array : - ");
    printingArray(a, false);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The Factors of the Resultant Array :-");
    printingArray(a,true);
}

// Printing the Array
public static void printingArray(NumberFactorPair[] a, boolean factors) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print
          ((factors ? a[i].factorCount : a[i].number) + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

The field `factorCount` is derived from `number`, but exists so that the number of factors for an instance is calculated only once.